# Why does host name have 'child' in it

Tags: 18.04, hostname

When I installed Ubuntu 18.04 into this computer I picked a username = 'test' and computer name = 'abc'. However it set my hostname to be abc-**child**.
So on my terminal I see `test@abc-child:~$`

Why did it add 'child' to my computer name? Did I mistakenly install it into a partition or something?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for adding a bounty so early in your AU career.  You'll get that back easily from upvotes. :-)

Comment: Never seen anything like this. Hostname should be set by admin. It could in theory default to machine brand/model. Very peculiar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

There's absolutely **nothing wrong with any name** so long as it meets the standards for domain names and doesn't conflict with another device on the network at the time. **The hostname does NOT indicate failure**, success, or anything else. A name is entirely your choice and can be changed at will as @Rinzwind's answer shows.  Initially, the hostname is derived from the network, or username with a suffix derived from various hardware attributes, but **the installer *always* shows the hostname during the installation** in an editable text box and thus you "approved" it.

**If your network is plugged in**

During installation, the installer will obtain the machine name from the network (by using the Reverse DNS entry e.g. `dig -x $DHCPAssignedIP`).  Some routers are smart in that they have certain agreed name suggestions when they have no assignment, e.g. machineX-child.localnet.priv.

It's possible that the DNS resolver on your network "suggested" that as a name, but you will certainly have approved it at the network-naming step in the installer.

**If you're not connected to *any* network during the installation.**

The hostname is actually derived from the username as "${username}-${suffix}", as in the [ubiquity source here](https://git.launchpad.net/ubiquity/tree/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-usersetup.py#n78).  The suffix is determined either [by calling your DMI here](https://git.launchpad.net/ubiquity/tree/ubiquity/misc.py#n618) or, failing that, `laptop-detect`.

**Initial "Who Are You" screen.**

[image: Initial "Who Are You" screen.]

**"Who Are You" screen after entering "Your name".**

[image: "Who Are You" screen after entering "Your name".]

So, to answer your original question, the most likely scenario is that your motherboard "DMI" is supplying the word "child".  You can investigate by calling:

```
dmidecode --quiet --string system-manufacturer
dmidecode --quiet --string system-version
dmidecode --quiet --string system-product-name
```

...since that's what [Ubiquity does here](https://git.launchpad.net/ubiquity/tree/ubiquity/misc.py#n618).

That's probably more than you wanted to know, but I was curious! :-D

Comment: Interesting! Strangely, I was not connected to any external network at the time of installation (no wireless card/ethernet cable). Could this still be the case? Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer for non-network installation.

Comment: More than I needed to know, but exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

It is the network name. No idea why -child was added but see `/etc/hosts`. It will be there. Example from my machine:

```
rinzwind@rinzwind-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   rinzwind-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop
```

and it will also be in `/etc/hostname`:

```
rinzwind@rinzwind-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ more /etc/hostname
rinzwind-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop
```

Change it to something else, like "abc" with:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname abc
```

and both will change to abc.

Comment: I'd not recommend manually editing `/etc/hosts` only. You also have to change `/etc/hostname` at least. My preferred way is `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname NAME`.

Comment: ah yes. my memory is getting bad :=)

Comment: What do you mean by the network name? Hmmm, unfortunately my issue isn't changing the name. I am just worried that I did my installation incorrectly which is why Ubuntu defaulted my hostname to abc-child. For example perhaps I did not mount my file system on `/` which is why the name was suffixed with `child`.